# How to login into Drupal using Google Apps username and password?

Tags: authentication, drupal-6, openid, google-authentication

Can you please give me the steps for How to login into Drupal 6 using Google Apps username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Enable "OpenID" module in modules list. You will get a new link in the login block called "Login using OpenID". Here you find some documentation about OpenID module (in drupal core from version 6) http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/openid

Or try this abandoned module by Google: http://drupal.org/project/friendconnect (not recommended)